# Using a stored procedure as subquery

Tags: mysql, stored-procedures

I've create a stored procedure in MySQL like the this

```
CREATE DEFINER=`root`@`localhost` PROCEDURE `my_proc`(IN var1 VARCHAR(25))
BEGIN
select (sum(er)*9)/(out/3) as era from table1 where id = var1 group by id;
END
```

I have another table that I'd like to get this information from.  I'd like to do something like this (pseudo code)

```
select id, column1, column2, (call my_proc(table1.id)) as era from table1
```

Basiclly I'm having my stored procedure calculate some information and return it as a column into that query.

Is a stored procedure the right solution here?

**Note in the pseudo-query the table name is supposed to be the same as in the stored procedure.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can define a stored function instead of a stored procedure.

```
CREATE DEFINER=`root`@`localhost` FUNCTION `my_func`(IN var1 VARCHAR(25))
  RETURNS NUMERIC(9,2)
BEGIN
  RETURN (SELECT (SUM(er)*9)/(out/3) AS era FROM table1 WHERE id = var1);
END
```

Then you can call it simply as you would call a function:

```
SELECT id, column1, column2, my_func(table1.id) AS era FROM table1
```

The stored function must be guaranteed to return a single scalar to be usable in your select-list.

I removed the GROUP BY, since it's superfluous.

The example above is kind of suspicious, because there's no reason to call a function like this to calculate the SUM over a single row. But I guess you have something more complex in mind.