# mySQL : Executing Stored Procedure on Select Query Result Set

Tags: mysql, stored-procedures

My apologies is this is answered some where - I cannot seem to find it, and think it may not be possible.

In short, I have a select query that gets built for a non-trivial keyword search page.  The problem has come up by where my client wants to run some math calculations on each search result on the fly (data cannot be stored / pre-calculated!).  I'm doing it now by page of results (limit is controlled in sql), so I just run the calculations on the results displayed at that time.

But this doesn't cut it for sorting or filtering of ALL the results, since I'm only generating the math on the page of results for display.

The math lives in a few php functions that also make queries... so I managed to pull all that into one "function", which I can create a stored procedure from, I'm pretty confident.

What I'm NOT confident about is, how will I incorporate that procedure with my search query and its result set, so that it fires all at once and returns me one result set?  In other words, it would be great if I could run something like:

(silly psuedo-code)

```
SELECT name, price, (CALL get_rank) as rank WHERE name = 'keyword' ORDER BY rank
```

I hope this makes sense, and is somehow possible with mySQL.  Otherwise, if the issue I'm having is understood, and someone has another suggestion, that'd be just as great, thanks!

Comment: possible duplicate of [Using a stored procedure as subquery](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23071752/using-a-stored-procedure-as-subquery)

Comment: ahhhh.. stored "functions" - now that's new to me!  Thanks, Bill, I think that'll do it - I'll post back upon success!