# mysql in clause use procedure instead subquery

Tags: php, mysql, stored-procedures

I have created a procedure which returns a single column of officeid

```
call officetree(15);
```

I need to get list of employee  under officeid's return by **officetree** procedure

```
select * from master_employee where officeid in ( here i want put my officeids return from procedure)
```

Is this possible to achieve this if yes what is the syntax for that.

Inside the procedure

> Below ofcid is parameter of procedure

```
select  `ofc_id`
 from (select * from master_office
     order by `ofc_parent_id`, `ofc_id`) master_office,
    (select @pv := ofcid) office
 where (find_in_set(`ofc_parent_id`, @pv) > 0 
and @pv := concat(@pv, ',', `ofc_id`)) or ofc_id=ofcid
```

Comment: Please post the procedure code.

Comment: Can i post query inside the proc or whole procedure code..??

Comment: Well.. Since the answer to your question is "No", you might be interested in alternative ways to solve the problem. But first we need to know what your procedure is doing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, AFAIK, you can not use a SP as sub query in MySQL.

Ref: [Using a stored procedure as subquery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23071752/using-a-stored-procedure-as-subquery)

Ref: https://forums.mysql.com/read.php?10,556522,556538#msg-556538

`Is it possible to call stored procs in MySQL 5.5 subqueries.
    No.`

And for a suggestion, use stored procedure as few as possible (my ten-year experience tells me)

Answer (score 0):

I think there is no way to use a stored procedure result like a subquery.

Your alternatives:

1. Use the statement from the procedure as subquery.
2. Fetch the IDs from the SP in PHP and execute a second query with the fetched IDs. `select * from master_employee where officeid in ( list of previously fetched IDs )`
3. Use a more powerfull design for the tree structure like "materialized path" or "transitive closure table"